# CSS file not loading in my HTML page but ok on VS Code live server

Tags: html, css

The CSS file loads when I use the Live Server extension in *Visual Studio Code*, but doesn't load when I open `index.html` directly in the browser.

The path to the CSS is correct, I double-checked everything, changing UTF-8 to windows-1252 did not help. I looked through everything carefully and I don’t see why the CSS is not loading.

CSS declared like this :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/style.css">
```

Comment: The path `/styles/style.css` is absolute (starting from the domain) and not relative. Just remove the leading slash.

Comment: Click view page source and click on your CSS link. If it doesn't load anything, it means it is not connected.

Answer (score 0):

The path `/styles/style.css` you set is **relative to the domain**, so this
is why it doesn't work when you open the HTML file locally.

When *VS Code* runs the server, you probably have `http://localhost:6448/index.htm` or something similar in your browser.
The leading slash in the path to your CSS will work, but only if the
`index.htm` is at the root of your project directory.

If you had `http://localhost:6448/folder/index.htm` and the
CSS file is stored under `http://localhost:6448/folder/styles/style.css`
then you would also have the same problem with the live server because
the leading slash tells the browser to start from the domain and will
try to load `http://localhost:6448/styles/style.css`, which doesn't exist.

So remove the leading slash to make it relative to the HTML file :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
```